# With Fossil source control, does the "fossil clone" command have the exact same effect as if you just copy the repository file manually?

Tags: fossil

With Fossil source control, does the "fossil clone" command have the exact same effect as if you just copy the repository file manually?

Could I just put the repository file on a usb stick and transfer it to another computer instead of calling fossil clone?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, it is not the same.

Differences are:

- User account control is per-repository.
- Artifacts such as private branches and their contents are not pulled
- Everything that `fossil scrub --verily --private` would suppress is typically not pulled (see `fossil help scrub`)
- Autosync URL is automatically set when you clone, creating a dependency link. Of course you can set it later with `fossil remote-url`

But if you use the repositories for your personal use on both sides you can just copy the repository, there is no problem doing a simple file copy. In order to merge your repositories, do not copy the most recent to the oldest, but set the sync URL and do a sync between them. It is quicker and safer as it will merge changes made **on both sides**, preventing any loss of changes.